# Image manipulation tool on my website

Tags: image-manipulation

I would like to ask if anyone knows a software that can be modified and used on my website. I need a tool that will be able to add multiple images resize and move theme. Something like [THIS](http://services.snipshot.com/edit/1l4pgvgbkk?reopen=true) but with multiple images support...

Beside that I need a canvas to be fix (width, height, dpi...) So the produced image will always have the same specifications...

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

nothing beats http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: I guess it is a software to install on computer... What I am looking web based software to integrate it on my website...

Comment: oh sorry... I see it is for PHP too will try and report back! Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for something like this: http://www.streetshirts.co.uk/creation.aspx